# Services or lazy loading

Tags: java, design-patterns, lazy-loading, service-layer

I have a little design question: What would be preferred between using lazy loading or a service to load fields?

For example:

Let's say with have a **City** class and an **Attraction** class and there are many attractions related to a city (more than 100 for example).
Would you use a lazy loaded field in the **City** class and just call

`city.getAttractions();` or 
would you prefer a **Service** to get the attractions

`attractionsService.getAttractionsForCity(city);`?

I saw the both uses in different places and I read about lazy loading's drawbacks and I am confused.

Another scenario is a City having Pictures associated. So, using `city.getPictures();` or `picturesService.getPicture(city);`?